# Specific regex dice rolling replacement and calculation

Tags: regex

I am trying to programme a regex to use in a virtual tabletop (VTT) for my D&D game.

The input is a standard string: "hp ";
followed by a number (range 1-2000 ish);
followed by a bracketed dice expression (eg 2d10+4 meaning roll 2 ten sided dice and add four to the sum of the two dice).

The number between hp and the dice expression is the average score for the dice expression - in this example would be 5.5 (the average score on a ten sided dice) times two plus four = 15. Input string eg:

hp 15 (2d10+4)

I would like a regex to identify the string and replace the average number with the maximum roll possible. In the above example replace 15 with 24. Is that possible with regex? My VTT is Java based - would I need to calculate the maximum after identifying the string and then replace the number in Java rather than in the regex?

I think I have the individual pieces, but the replace is failing me:

Find the number after "hp"
?<=[hH][pP]\s)[0-9]+

Find the 2d10+4
[0-9]+d[0-9]+\s?[\+\-]?\s?[^a-zA-Z]?[0-9]?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regexes are not suitable for doing arithmetic, you can only hardcode the answers to specific calculations, so it only makes sense to do that if you only have a few possible calculations (and I'd argue not even then because such hardcoding is bad and obfuscates intent).

Java can however tell you where the match of the number found by the regex begins and ends in the string. That would be useful for replacement purposes.